# multithreaded blas in python/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing, blas

I am trying to implement a large number of matrix-matrix multiplications in Python. Initially, I assumed that NumPy would use automatically my threaded BLAS libraries since I built it against those libraries. However, when I look at [**top**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_%28software%29) or something else it seems like the code does not use threading at all.

Any ideas what is wrong or what I can do to easily use BLAS performance?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Like: How large `large number` actually is? What are the shapes of your matrices? What are your current timings? Characterization of your HW? What kind of performance improvements you are expecting (hoping)? Thanks

Comment: @eat: the matrices will be roughly 1600x1600 (double). The code does tons of matrix-matrix multiplications since I am solving a very large system of coupled ODEs. Just using blas in Fortran instead of looping naively through the matrix multiplications speeds up things significantly. Threading on my system should have probably done the same thing. I was hoping for speedup of order 10 :).

Comment: Care to present the relevant part of your code such a way that any one can harness it at their own platform? (BTW, are your matrices close to full rank? If they happen to be low rank ones, then alternative avenues exists to speed up calculations). Thanks

Comment: Despite the fact that I accepted the answer below I wanted to comment on additional issues I encountered: The first numpy distro that I had installed did not support multithreading. I finally installed the epd distro but found that it had set a shell variable MKL_NUM_THREADS=1. I have no idea why it that though but once this line was removed in my bash_profile the problem was solved. A friend who uses linux instead of Mac OS did not encounter this issue with epd.

Comment: @Lucas, I removed that variable as well from the .bash_profile and I as well am using the EPD on Mac OS X. My problem is not fixed. Numpy.dot is still using only one core. Is there anything else you did?

Comment: @Nino: Are you doing matrix-matrix multiplication w/ numpy.dot?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, I got it working though. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Not all of NumPy uses BLAS, only some functions -- specifically `dot()`, `vdot()`, and `innerproduct()` and several functions from the `numpy.linalg` module.  Also note that many NumPy operations are limited by memory bandwidth for large arrays, so an optimised implementation is unlikely to give any improvement.  Whether multi-threading can give better performance if you are limited by memory bandwidth heavily depends on your hardware.

Comment: That doesn't sound good. I was hoping that I could solve this problem somehow in python. Do you think it would pay of to use something like weave to do the matrix multiplications in C or Fortran provided I want to use a particular function from numpy that calls then the hard coded matrix multiplication subroutine?

Comment: @Lucas: matrix multiplication in NumPy should be done by `numpy.dot()`, also internally.  But without knowing what you are actually doing, it's next to impossible to give further advice.  Maybe you want to open a new uqestion.

Answer (score 116):

*I already posted this in another thread but I think it fits better in this one:*

### UPDATE (30.07.2014):

I re-run the the benchmark on our new HPC. 
Both the hardware as well as the software stack changed from the setup in the original answer.

I put the results in a [google spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jq0fDv-0ySMCF6qB22A13Aqf0TjAn449c6-TWrfViJ0/edit?usp=sharing) (contains also the results from the original answer).

### Hardware

Our HPC has two different nodes one with Intel Sandy Bridge CPUs and one with the newer Ivy Bridge CPUs:

**Sandy** (MKL, OpenBLAS, ATLAS):

- **CPU**: 2 x 16 Intel(R) Xeon(R) E2560 Sandy Bridge @ 2.00GHz (16 Cores)
- **RAM**: 64 GB

**Ivy** (MKL, OpenBLAS, ATLAS):

- **CPU**: 2 x 20 Intel(R) Xeon(R) E2680 V2 Ivy Bridge @ 2.80GHz (20 Cores, with HT = 40 Cores)
- **RAM**: 256 GB

### Software

The software stack is for both nodes the sam. Instead of **GotoBLAS2**, **OpenBLAS** is used and there is also a **multi-threaded ATLAS** BLAS that is set to 8 threads (hardcoded).

- **OS**: Suse
- **Intel Compiler**: ictce-5.3.0
- **Numpy:** 1.8.0
- **OpenBLAS:** 0.2.6
- **ATLAS:**: 3.8.4

### Dot-Product Benchmark

Benchmark-code is the same as below. However for the new machines I also ran the benchmark for matrix sizes **5000** and **8000**.
The table below includes the benchmark results from the original answer (renamed: MKL --> Nehalem MKL, Netlib Blas --> Nehalem Netlib BLAS, etc)

[image: Matrix multiplication (sizes=[1000,2000,3000,5000,8000])]

**Single threaded performance:**
[image: single threaded performance]

**Multi threaded performance (8 threads):** 
[image: multi-threaded (8 threads) performance]

**Threads vs Matrix size (Ivy Bridge MKL)**:
[image: Matrix-size vs threads]

### Benchmark Suite

[image: benchmark suite]

**Single threaded performance:**
[image]

**Multi threaded (8 threads) performance:**
[image]

### Conclusion

The new benchmark results are similar to the ones in the original answer. **OpenBLAS** and **MKL** perform on the same level, with the exception of **Eigenvalue** test. 
The **Eigenvalue** test performs only reasonably well on **OpenBLAS** in **single threaded mode**.
In multi-threaded mode the performance is worse.

The **"Matrix size vs threads chart"** also show that although MKL as well as OpenBLAS generally scale well with number of cores/threads,it depends on the size of the matrix. For small matrices adding more cores won't improve performance very much.

There is also approximately 30% performance increase from **Sandy Bridge** to **Ivy Bridge** which might be either due to higher clock rate (+ 0.8 Ghz) and/or better architecture.

---

### Original Answer (04.10.2011):

Some time ago I had to optimize some linear algebra calculations/algorithms which were written in python using numpy and BLAS so I benchmarked/tested different numpy/BLAS configurations.

Specifically I tested:

- Numpy with ATLAS
- Numpy with [GotoBlas2](http://www.tacc.utexas.edu/tacc-projects/gotoblas2) (1.13)
- Numpy with MKL (11.1/073)
- Numpy with Accelerate Framework (Mac OS X)

I did run two different benchmarks:

1. simple dot product of matrices with different sizes
2. Benchmark suite which can be found [here](http://dpinte.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/numpy-performance-improvement-with-the-mkl/).

Here are my results:

### Machines

**Linux** (MKL, ATLAS, No-MKL, GotoBlas2):

- **OS**: Ubuntu Lucid 10.4 64 Bit.
- **CPU**: 2 x 4 Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5504 @ 2.00GHz (8 Cores)
- **RAM**: 24 GB
- **Intel Compiler**: 11.1/073
- **Scipy**: 0.8
- **Numpy**: 1.5

**Mac Book Pro** (Accelerate Framework):

- **OS**: Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6)
- **CPU**: 1 Intel Core 2 Duo 2.93 Ghz (2 Cores)
- **RAM**: 4 GB
- **Scipy**: 0.7
- **Numpy**: 1.3

**Mac Server** (Accelerate Framework):

- **OS**: Mac OS X Snow Leopard Server (10.6)
- **CPU**: 4 X Intel(R) Xeon(R) E5520 @ 2.26 Ghz (8 Cores)
- **RAM**: 4 GB
- **Scipy**: 0.8
- **Numpy**: 1.5.1

### Dot product benchmark

**Code**:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.random_sample((size,size))
b = np.random.random_sample((size,size))
%timeit np.dot(a,b)
```

**Results**:

```
    System        |  size = 1000  | size = 2000 | size = 3000 |
netlib BLAS       |  1350 ms      |   10900 ms  |  39200 ms   |    
ATLAS (1 CPU)     |   314 ms      |    2560 ms  |   8700 ms   |     
MKL (1 CPUs)      |   268 ms      |    2110 ms  |   7120 ms   |
MKL (2 CPUs)      |    -          |       -     |   3660 ms   |
MKL (8 CPUs)      |    39 ms      |     319 ms  |   1000 ms   |
GotoBlas2 (1 CPU) |   266 ms      |    2100 ms  |   7280 ms   |
GotoBlas2 (2 CPUs)|   139 ms      |    1009 ms  |   3690 ms   |
GotoBlas2 (8 CPUs)|    54 ms      |     389 ms  |   1250 ms   |
Mac OS X (1 CPU)  |   143 ms      |    1060 ms  |   3605 ms   |
Mac Server (1 CPU)|    92 ms      |     714 ms  |   2130 ms   |
```

[image: Dot product benchmark - chart]

### Benchmark Suite

**Code**:
For additional information about the benchmark suite see [here](http://dpinte.wordpress.com/2010/01/15/numpy-performance-improvement-with-the-mkl/).

**Results**:

```
    System        | eigenvalues   |    svd   |   det  |   inv   |   dot   |
netlib BLAS       |  1688 ms      | 13102 ms | 438 ms | 2155 ms | 3522 ms |
ATLAS (1 CPU)     |   1210 ms     |  5897 ms | 170 ms |  560 ms |  893 ms |
MKL (1 CPUs)      |   691 ms      |  4475 ms | 141 ms |  450 ms |  736 ms |
MKL (2 CPUs)      |   552 ms      |  2718 ms |  96 ms |  267 ms |  423 ms |
MKL (8 CPUs)      |   525 ms      |  1679 ms |  60 ms |  137 ms |  197 ms |  
GotoBlas2 (1 CPU) |  2124 ms      |  4636 ms | 147 ms |  456 ms |  743 ms |
GotoBlas2 (2 CPUs)|  1560 ms      |  3278 ms | 116 ms |  295 ms |  460 ms |
GotoBlas2 (8 CPUs)|   741 ms      |  2914 ms |  82 ms |  262 ms |  192 ms |
Mac OS X (1 CPU)  |   948 ms      |  4339 ms | 151 ms |  318 ms |  566 ms |
Mac Server (1 CPU)|  1033 ms      |  3645 ms |  99 ms |  232 ms |  342 ms |
```

[image: Benchmark suite - chart]

### Installation

Installation of **MKL** included installing the complete Intel Compiler Suite which is pretty straight forward. However because of some bugs/issues configuring and compiling numpy with MKL support was a bit of a hassle.

**GotoBlas2** is a small package which can be easily compiled as a shared library. However because of a [bug](http://geekeeway.blogspot.com/2010/06/install-and-link-gotoblas-in-eclipse.html) you have to re-create the shared library after building it in order to use it with numpy.
In addition to this building it for multiple target plattform didn't work for some reason. So I had to create an **.so** file for each platform for which i want to have an optimized **libgoto2.so** file.

If you install numpy from Ubuntu's repository it will automatically install and configure numpy to use **ATLAS**. Installing **ATLAS** from source can take some time and requires some additional steps (fortran, etc).

If you install numpy on a Mac OS X machine with **Fink** or **Mac Ports** it will either configure numpy to use **ATLAS** or **Apple's Accelerate Framework**. 
You can check by either running ldd on the  **numpy.core._dotblas** file or calling **numpy.show_config()**.

### Conclusions

**MKL** performs best closely followed by **GotoBlas2**.
In the **eigenvalue** test GotoBlas2 performs surprisingly worse than expected. Not sure why this is the case.
**Apple's Accelerate Framework** performs really good especially in single threaded mode (compared to the other BLAS implementations).

Both **GotoBlas2** and **MKL** scale very well with number of threads. So if you have to deal with big matrices running it on multiple threads will help a lot.

In any case don't use the default **netlib blas** implementation because it is way too slow for any serious computational work.

On our cluster I also installed **AMD's ACML** and performance was similar to **MKL** and **GotoBlas2**. I don't have any numbers tough.

I personally would recommend to use **GotoBlas2** because it's easier to install and it's free.

If you want to code in C++/C also check out [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) which is supposed to outperform **MKL/GotoBlas2** in some [cases](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Benchmark) and is also pretty easy to use.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.  Do youknow if Apple's Accelerate Framework takes advantage of multiple cores or of hyperthreading?  I guess not, because your "Mac Server" has 4 cores, as far as I can tell, but can you confirm this?  Also, for ATLAS, are you implying that it can only use 1 core (I only see results for this case)?

Comment: The Accelerate Framework did only use one core by default. To be honest I don't know if you can set it to use more than one core. There is nothing about that on the developers page: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#featuredarticles/AccelerateFrameworkData/_index.html

Concerning ATLAS: The default ATLAS installation is single threaded. However there is also a multi-threaded ATLAS version (AT93 or so). See here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gcbd/vignettes/gcbd.pdf

Comment: @EOL The apple accelerate used all four of my cores on my mountain lion mac. Numpy 1.6.1 on apple python 2.7.2

Comment: @Ümit How do you make numpy use multi-threading on a cluster? I got numpy to multi-thread on a single laptop (Apple python and another machine using enthought built against MKL), but when I send a job to our cluster asking to use 8 cores (on a machine that has numpy built with multi-threaded blas), it is not faster than using a single core. My next question is how do you actually know which library numpy functions are using? I do 
`>>> import inspect
>>> import numpy as np
>>> inspect.getmodule(np.dot)
'numpy.core._dotblas'

I get this on all three different pythons (apple, enthought, cluster)

Comment: @Nino: It depends against which kind of multi-threaded blas library your numpy installation on the cluster is configured. In our case (using MKL) you can set the number of cores that are used by the [MKL_NUM_THREADS](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/showthread.php?t=84282) environment variable.
Regarding checking against which library numpy functions are using I usually do an `ldd` on the ``_dotblas.so`` file. It will show you against which libraries the so files is linked (in case of MKL the mkl so's, etc).

Comment: @Ümit: When I run the ldd command on our linux cluster, I get a strange [output](http://pastebin.com/QkzYT4iL). Could you help me decode this? I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Nino: it looks like your numpy installation doesn't use any custom BLAS library. For example if you configure numpy with MKL it should also link the dotblas.so against the mkl libraries or in case of ATLAS (i.e libatlas.so, etc).

Comment: Nearly five years later, **this answer remains epic.** This is _still_ the canonical Numpy acceleration benchmark. Only one addition could possibly up the epic ante: a **[BLIS](https://github.com/flame/blis)**-linked Numpy benchmark. Beggars can't be choosers, however. I choose you, [Ümit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/356594/%c3%9cmit).

Comment: @CecilCurry: Thanks ;-) I will give it a shot, as soon as I have a bit of time

Comment: @CecilCurry: After doing a bit of more research (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/blis-devel/gwSOFLUz2g0) I don't think BLIS will give us different results than the BLAS libraries at least not for the benchmark we are running (dot product, etc).

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that because Matrix x Matrix multiplication is memory constrained that adding extra cores on the same memory hierarchy doesn't give you much. Of course, if you're seeing substantial speedup when you switch to your Fortran implementation then I might be incorrect.

My understanding is that proper caching is far more important for these sorts of problems than compute power. Presumably BLAS does this for you.

For a simple test you could try installing [Enthought's](http://www.enthought.com/products/getepd.php) python distribution for comparison. They link against Intel's [Math Kernel Library](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math_Kernel_Library) which I believe harnesses multiple cores if available.

Answer (score 1):

Have you heard of MAGMA? 
Matrix Algebra on GPU and Multicore Architecture
http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/

> The MAGMA project aims to develop a dense linear algebra library similar to LAPACK but for heterogeneous/hybrid architectures, starting with current "Multicore+GPU" systems.

Comment: **MCVE**-alike culture also demands to be quantitative -- state **what** process / took **how much time** to complete / under **what particular circumstances**. Technical marketing tends to omit these quantitative verifiable facts, so do not hesitate to either request them, or generate them on your own, or rather do not re-trombone PR-motivated texts. Do not forget, multicore, the more GPU engines, suffer from their (internal) latency masking architectures and hit the I/O-bandwidth barriers sooner than later right due to their focus on number crunching. True parallel designs experience this