# Make python use more resources in calculations

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7, cpu-usage, approximation

Hi I'm trying to do some matrix calculations using python. The problem is there seems to be a limit of how much CPU will the process consume (about 13% of my Core i7).

Is there a way I can make it use more resources?

Comment: I think there is no way of doing that, thru python, although I also belive there is no limitations on CPU usage. *(try to get in an infinite loop, and your CPU usage will be 100%)* But, if you need more power, think about implementing your algorythm in `Cython`.

Comment: I think you run on a single core, and you use it at 100%. Try to go multithread.

Comment: how do you define 13% CPU usage, is that 13% of one core or 13% of your 4+4 cores (because 1/8 = 0.125...)... the python interpeter is running in one thread so you can't (to m knowlenge) get higher than 100% of 1 core... you can however gain a speed up of 10-100 if you use numpy for matrix calcuations :)

Comment: @azorius as process explorer defines it.. I've just looked at the CPU column there...

Comment: try to do: "while True: x = 1+1" if this goes to 100% then your arrays are io limited, if this also goes to 13% then you can only get faster by a) using threads b) using numpy c) writing a c extention d) other fancy stuff

Comment: i7 is probably a quad-core with hyperthreading, which amounts to 8 cores, 1 / 8 = 0.125 ~= 13%. You are definitely running one a single core. If possible you should take a look at multiprocessing.

Comment: @Blubber oh snap didn't think about the HT 'cores' lol now the 13% does makes sense and yes the endless loop consumed 13% as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people in the comments pointed out, you're running only on one of your 8 (4 physical, 4 virtual) cores.

If you aren't doing this for a programming exercise but instead you're really interested in numerical programming or data analysis in python, you might want to take a close look at numpy. That package provides fast array/vector/matrix types and operations them, and (supposedly) can do multi threaded dot products (see [multithreaded blas in python/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260068/multithreaded-blas-in-python-numpy) ).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "4 physical"?

Comment: edited for clarity. Well, 4 physical cores, 4 virtual cores = 8 total cores ... not sure though if this is the correct naming...