# Parallel matrix-vector multiplication in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, blas

I have a (40000,40000) array A and vector v of size 40000. When i run

```
u = A.dot(b)
```

only one core is used. Is there any standard way to make it run in parallel?

Using the Anaconda distribution on RedHat.
I have seen a lot of questions/answers about BLAS/PBLAS/ATLAS/OpenBLAS but i cannot find my way around it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260068/multithreaded-blas-in-python-numpy

Comment: @NPE This is one of the answers i read, but it says nothing on how to install all those libraries/check if i already have them

Comment: Try numpy.__config__.show()