# Which numpy methods are threaded?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

[I'm reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5260509/353337) that some numpy methods make use of threading in BLAS if available; specifically `numpy.dot` & friends.

Which other functions do?

Comment: I think this question is probably off-topic because any such list would evolve over time (and thereby invalidate answers). Also as far as I know should this be seen as implementation detail the numpy developers can change whenever feel like it. However I think most of `np.linalg` uses BLAS/ATLAS (or similar "packages") and may or may not be threaded.

Comment: @MSeifert I'm not sure I follow. Are you saying anything that may at some point in the future change is off-topic? In practice, any such list could be tied to a `numpy` version/configuration, couldn't it?

Comment: @PaulPanzer I probably should've said "too broad" instead of off-topic. It doesn't only depend on `numpy` alone. Besides `numpy` it also depends on the used "package": Blas, OpenBlas, Accelerate, MKL, ... and the configurations there.

Comment: @MSeifert fair enough. And now I'll go back to my habit of staying out of politics ;-)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the suggestions. Of course @MSeifert is correct pointing out that threading also depends on Numpy's linear algrebra backend. That's why I wrote `if available`; certainly it isn't clear enough. Anyhow, this question is probably better asked on the numpy mailing list.