# Which operations in numpy/scipy are multithreaded?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, scipy

I'm working on an algorithm, and I've made no attempt to parallelize it other than just by using numpy/scipy. Looking at `htop`, sometimes the code uses all of my cores and sometimes just one. I'm considering adding parallelism to the single-threaded portions using `multiprocessing` or something similar.

Assuming that I have all of the parallel BLAS/MKL libraries, is there some rule of thumb that I can follow to guess whether a numpy/scipy ufunc is going to be multithreaded or not? Even better, is there some place where this is documented?

To try to figure this out, I've looked at: https://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/ParallelProgramming, [Python: How do you stop numpy from multithreading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053671/python-how-do-you-stop-numpy-from-multithreading), [multithreaded blas in python/numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260068/multithreaded-blas-in-python-numpy).

Comment: For future readers, the joblib maintainers have a cool package for controlling threads in blas/etc: https://github.com/joblib/threadpoolctl

Answer (score 2):

You may try to take IDP package ([Intel® Distribution for Python](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python)) which contains versions of  NumPy*, SciPy*, and scikit-learn* with integrated Intel® Math Kernel Library.

This would give you threading of all Lapack routines automatically whether this make sense to do.
Here you find out the list of threaded mkl’s functions : 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-linux-developer-guide-openmp-threaded-functions-and-problems

Comment: Why did you put an asterisk next to the package names in your answer? The same is used in Intel's documentation (and others), and I have never seen it explained.

Answer (score 1):

The routines intrinsic to `numpy` and `scipy` allow single threads by default. You can change that if you so choose.

```
# encoding: utf-8
# module numpy.core.multiarray
# from /path/to/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.cpython-36m-darwin.so
# by generator 1.145
# no doc
# no imports

# Variables with simple values

ALLOW_THREADS = 1
```

When compiling `numpy`, you can control threading by changing `NPY_ALLOW_THREADS`:

```
./core/include/numpy/ufuncobject.h:#if NPY_ALLOW_THREADS
./core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:        #define NPY_ALLOW_THREADS 1
```

As for the external libraries, I've mostly found `numpy` and `scipy` to wrap around legacy Fortran code (`QUADPACK`, `LAPACK`, `FITPACK` ... so on). All the subroutines in these libraries compute on single threads.

As for the MKL dependencies, the SO posts you link to sufficiently answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

please try to set the global variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS`. It works for my scipy and numpy. The functions I use are,

`ling.inv()` and `A.dot(B)`