# How to use multiprocessing to drop duplicates in a very big list?

Tags: python, optimization, duplicates, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

Let's say I have a huge list containing random numbers for example

```
L = [random.randrange(0,25000000000) for _ in range(1000000000)]
```

I need to get rid of the duplicates in this list

I wrote this code for lists containing a smaller number of elements

```
def remove_duplicates(list_to_deduplicate):
seen = set()
result=[]
for i in list_to_deduplicate:
    if i not in seen:
        result.append(i)
        seen.add(i)
return result
```

In the code above I create a set so I can memorize what numbers have already appeared in the list I'm working on if the number is not in the set then I add it to the result list I need to return and save it in the set so it won't be added again in the result list

Now for 1000000 number in a list all is good I can get a result fast but for numbers superior to let's say 1000000000 problems arise I need to use the different cores on my machine to try and break up the problem and then combine the results from multiple processes

My first guess was to make a set accessible to all processes but many complications will arise
How can a process read while maybe another one is adding to the set and I don't even know if it is possible to share a set between processes I know we can use a Queue or a pipe but I'm not sure on how to use it

Can someone give me an advice on what is the best way to solve this problem
I am open to any new idea

Comment: Why don't you convert the whole list to a set and back to a list instead?

Comment: `result = list(set(list_to_deduplicate))`

Comment: Thank you for your comments for 10000000 numbers my function did it in 10 seconds while list(set(list_to_deduplicate)) completed the work in 8.9 seconds but for numbers bigger than that for example 1000000000 I don't think these functions can get the job done I need to use multithreading this is why I implemented this function in the first place so I can get the results from the different processes.

Comment: For lists the size that you are contemplating, memory is going to be your issue, not CPU speed.  Unless you are using some kind of supercomputer you're going to die at the swap disk.  Even if you get multi-threading working, you aren't going to like the results because of memory issues.

Comment: Do you really need a list?  Sets are iterable Removing a duplicate from a list -  which dup,  first or last ?  Would you need to reassemble your original order?

Comment: A good approach is somewhat dependent on whether you receive the list all at once or one item at a time.  While not essential to know, if this is dealing with IP addresses or genomics, there are likely cookbook approaches available

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm skeptic even your greatest list is big enough so that multiprocessing would improve timings. Using numpy and *multithreading* is probably your best chance.

Multiprocessing introduces quite some overhead and increases memory consumption like @Frank Merrow rightly mentioned earlier.
That's not the case (to that extend) for multithreading, though. It's important to not mix these terms up because processes and threads are not the same.
Threads within the same process share their memory, distinct processes do not.

The problem with going multi-core in Python is the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which doesn't allow multiple threads (in the same process) to execute Python bytecode in parallel. Some C-extensions like numpy can release the GIL, this enables profiting from multi-core parallelism with multithreading. Here's your chance to get some speed up on top of a big improvement just by using numpy.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # .dummy uses threads
import numpy as np

r = np.random.RandomState(42).randint(0, 25000000000, 100_000_000)
n_threads = 8

result = np.unique(np.concatenate(
    Pool(n_threads).map(np.unique, np.array_split(r, n_threads)))
).tolist()
```

Use numpy and a thread-pool, split up the array, make the sub-arrays unique in separate threads, then concatenate the sub-arrays and make the recombined array once more unique again.
The final dropping of duplicates for the recombined array is necessary because within the sub-arrays only *local* duplicates can be identified.

For **low entropy data** (many duplicates) using [`pandas.unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html) instead of `numpy.unique` can be much faster. Unlike [`numpy.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) it also preserves order of appearance.

Note that using a thread-pool like above makes only sense if the numpy-function is **not already multi-threaded** [under the hood](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5260068/9059420) by calling into low-level math libraries. So, always test to see if it actually improves performance and don't take it for granted.

---

Tested with 100M random generated integers in the range:

- High entropy: 0 - 25_000_000_000  (199560 duplicates)
- Low entropy: 0 - 1000

## Code

```
import time
import timeit
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool  # .dummy uses threads

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def time_stmt(stmt, title=None):
    t = timeit.repeat(
        stmt=stmt,
        timer=time.perf_counter_ns, repeat=3, number=1, globals=globals()
    )
    print(f"\t{title or stmt}")
    print(f"\t\t{min(t) / 1e9:.2f} s")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    n_threads = 8  # machine with 8 cores (4 physical cores)

    stmt_np_unique_pool = \
"""
np.unique(np.concatenate(
    Pool(n_threads).map(np.unique, np.array_split(r, n_threads)))
).tolist()
"""

    stmt_pd_unique_pool = \
"""
pd.unique(np.concatenate(
    Pool(n_threads).map(pd.unique, np.array_split(r, n_threads)))
).tolist()
"""
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    print(f"\nhigh entropy (few duplicates) {'-' * 30}\n")
    r = np.random.RandomState(42).randint(0, 25000000000, 100_000_000)

    r = list(r)
    time_stmt("list(set(r))")

    r = np.asarray(r)
    # numpy.unique
    time_stmt("np.unique(r).tolist()")
    # pandas.unique
    time_stmt("pd.unique(r).tolist()")    
    # numpy.unique & Pool
    time_stmt(stmt_np_unique_pool, "numpy.unique() & Pool")
    # pandas.unique & Pool
    time_stmt(stmt_pd_unique_pool, "pandas.unique() & Pool")

    # ---
    print(f"\nlow entropy (many duplicates) {'-' * 30}\n")
    r = np.random.RandomState(42).randint(0, 1000, 100_000_000)

    r = list(r)
    time_stmt("list(set(r))")

    r = np.asarray(r)
    # numpy.unique
    time_stmt("np.unique(r).tolist()")
    # pandas.unique
    time_stmt("pd.unique(r).tolist()")
    # numpy.unique & Pool
    time_stmt(stmt_np_unique_pool, "numpy.unique() & Pool")
    # pandas.unique() & Pool
    time_stmt(stmt_pd_unique_pool, "pandas.unique() & Pool")
```

Like you can see in the timings below, just using numpy without multithreading already accounts for the biggest performance improvement. Also note `pandas.unique()` being faster than `numpy.unique()` (only) for many duplicates.

```
high entropy (few duplicates) ------------------------------

    list(set(r))
        32.76 s
    np.unique(r).tolist()
        12.32 s
    pd.unique(r).tolist()
        23.01 s
    numpy.unique() & Pool
        9.75 s
    pandas.unique() & Pool
        28.91 s

low entropy (many duplicates) ------------------------------

    list(set(r))
        5.66 s
    np.unique(r).tolist()
        4.59 s
    pd.unique(r).tolist()
        0.75 s
    numpy.unique() & Pool
        1.17 s
    pandas.unique() & Pool
        0.19 s
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this was really helpful and insightful ! Much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Can't say I like this, but it should work, after a fashion.

Divide the data in *N* readonly pieces. Distribute one per worker to research the data.  Everything is readonly, so it can all be shared. Each worker *i 1...N* checks its list against all the other 'future' lists *i+1...N*

Each worker *i* maintains a bit table for its *i+1...N*  lists noting if any of the its items hit any of the the future items.

When everyone is done, worker *i* sends it's bit table back to master where tit can be *AND*ed.  the zeroes then get deleted. No sorting no sets.  The checking is not fast, tho.

If you don't want to bother with multiple bit tables you can let every worker *i* write zeroes when they find a dup above their own region of responsibility.  HOWEVER, now you run into **real shared memory issues**.  For that matter, you could even let each work just delete dup above their region, but ditto.

Even dividing up the work begs the question. It's expensive for each worker to walk though everyone else's list for each of its own entries. *(N-1)*len(region)/2*.  Each worker could create a set of it's region, or sort it's region.  Either would permit faster checks, but the costs add up.